# backup triggers, functions and stored procedures with mariabackup

Tags: mariadb, mysql-backup

I need to backup my triggers, stored procedures and functions, but I can't found info about this at official mans mariabackup. For example, I found info about mysqldump, it backup triggers by default and stored procedures + functions with *--routines* option.
How I can to backup triggers, stored procedures and functions with mariabackup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MariaBackup stores trigger files by default, you don't need to do anything special for that. You can find the list of files in the [MariaDB KB](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/files-backed-up-by-mariabackup/).
Procedures and functions are stored in `mysql.proc`, so they are automatically backed up along with the table.